# How to save changes to an Entity using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I have an Entity `User` and an Entity `UserPage`
The User does not have a UserPage when you create him
Now I want to create a userpage and assign it to the user. This looks like this:

```
UserPage page= new UserPage([Attributes here]);
User user; (this is a User previously created, persisted and now fetched)
```

now I do the following:

```
user.setUserPage(page);
userPageEJB.persist(page);
```

now when I want to fetch the userPage of the user, I do:

```
User user= userEJB.getUserByID([userID here]);
UserPage page= user.getUserPage();
```

The problem now is, that the changes appear not to have been saved (the last line of code always returns null). How do I save them so I can fetch the page of a specific user?

Comment: Show the surrounding code. Is all of this running in the same transaction? How's that being managed?

Answer (score 0):

If User and UserPage have parent-child relation, use [CascadeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) mapping. Using this mapping JPA will translate change to entity state to corresponding DML statement:

```
class User{
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user",
    cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private UserPage userPage;
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing to check is the CascadeType of the relationship between UserPage and User ,you need to have at least a `CascadeType.PERSIST` , you can also use `CascadeType.ALL` depend on the definition of the relationship you have made. the second thing is to check if your code has been executed in a single transaction (whether a [BTM](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html) or [CTM](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html))to ensure that all modification have been flushed to the DB.